# Model validations causing error Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, model, controller

I have a form for people to donate. It requires email and a name. I have not yet added stripe.. just trying to get the form to work first and save their email/name to the db.

When I add a presence validation to my model, it won't accept anything. It just returns the f.error notification. When I get rid of validations, the form submits successfully but nothing is saved to the data base. The rails console simply returns nil for name and email.

Still new to rails, so probably something simple. Any recommendations would be awesome.

`donation.rb` (model):

```
class Donation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :name, :email

  validates :name,
  presence: true

  validates :email,
  presence: true
end
```

donations_controller:

```
class DonationsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @donation = Donation.new
  end

  def create
    @donation = Donation.new(params[donation_params])
    if @donation.valid?
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Thank you. We have received your donation."
    else
      flash[:alert] = "An error occurred, please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

private

  def donation_params
    params.require(:donation).permit(:name, :email)
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
get 'donations', to: 'donations#new', as: 'donations'
post 'donations', to: 'donations#create'
```

new.html.erb (donation view):

```
<body class ="CU">
  <div class="authform">
    <%= simple_form_for @donation, :url => donations_path do |f| %>
    <h1 style = "text-align:center; color:black;">Donate</h1>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Name', :autofocus => true, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: 'Email', class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit 'Donate', :class => 'btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-block' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</body>
```

Let me know if you need anything else. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part

```
@donation = Donation.new(params[donation_params])
```

should actually be:

```
@donation = Donation.new(donation_params)
```

Also your create method doesn't save the record. Use `save` instead of `valid?`

Also why did you put breakline in your validation definitions?

Also, use RESTful routes, that is:

```
resources :donations
```

instead of manually defining each route.

Also, since you use [strong params](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters), you don't need `attr_accessor` (which should have been `attr_accessible` it case of rails, but whatever).
You would use `attr_accessor` for defining virtual attributes, but I am sure it was not the case, since `name` and `email` are database backed fields.

And, finally, just walk through [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) - you'll find all needed info.

Comment: @Kathan doesn't need that `attr_accessor :name, :email` also.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. When I use `resources :donations` instead of manually defining the routes I get this error: `The action 'index' could not be found for DonationsController` However, i changed everything else and it works :D

Comment: Awesome. Last thing.. when I use `save?` instead of `valid?` I get the error `undefined method `save?'` I apologize for these questions. I will definitely have to go through the rails guide entirely. I have just been stuck on this all day. Thank you.

Comment: @Kathan my bad, `save` withoud `?`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not saving it, try this `if @donation.save` instead of `if @donation.valid?` in `create`